# Img float affecting centering

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a back button to my page, I put it in the top left corner and it is floating.

But since I added it in the centering of `track-image` has been affected, it is pushed over 3 rem, the width of the floating back button.

HTML

```
  <body>  
    <a href="entry.html" style="display: inline-block; float: left;">
      <img src="backArrow.png" style="width:3rem; margin: .5rem; float: left">
    </a>
    <div id="track">
      <img id="track-image" src="track.png">
      <p id="track-fraud"> Track Fraud </p><br>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
#track {
    text-align: center; 
}

#track-fraud {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 0;
}

#track-image {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    width: 10rem;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's difficult to visualize your intent based on the description. Sounds though like you float isn't even the way to go here though.

Comment: @ChrisW. I just want the button and the next div on the same line but i need the div centered on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use position: absolute on the button which will take it out of the document flow, so it will no longer push the other content over. https://jsfiddle.net/7frLasx5/

```
#track {
   text-align: center; 
}

.track-back {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}

#track-fraud {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 0;
}

#track-image {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    width: 10rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, I suggest you avoid float, as it comes with weird implications for the rest of the page.

Still, trying it on jsFiddle, float works in your context :

```css
.topContainer{
  background-color:black;
  width:90%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}

.backButton{
  float:left;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
}

.centerImage{
  background-color:blue;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
}

.topElement{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topContainer">
  <div class="backButton topElement"></div>
  <div class="centerImage topElement">
    TrackFraud
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe you should add "display:inline-block" to the elements of your top bar?

Comment: The center image is still shifted to the right, it is not centered on the page.

Comment: I am so sorry, you are completely right! Although far less beautiful, another way to solve what I posted would be to replace "float:left", in the backButton, by display:absolute and left:whatever the appropriate margin is. This solves the shift to the right of the center element, but it only works well if the topbar is always at the same position relative to the left of the screen.